# Add onsubmit to onclose

Tags: jquery

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery.cookie("FirstTimeVisitor") != 1) {
        jQuery('#basic-modal-content').modal({
            opacity: 80,
            display: true,
            overlayClose: true,
            onClose: function() { 
                jQuery.cookie("FirstTimeVisitor", "1", { expires: 720 }); 
                jQuery.modal.close(); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I would like `onSubmit` to do the same thing as `onClose` does. How can I add/combine the `onSubmit` to the `onClose` function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Define a named function, and use it in both places:

```
function closeModal() {
    jQuery.cookie("FirstTimeVisitor", "1", { expires: 720 }); 
    jQuery.modal.close(); 
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery.cookie("FirstTimeVisitor") != 1) {
        jQuery('#basic-modal-content').modal({
            opacity:80,
            display:true,
            overlayClose:true,
            onClose: closeModal,
            onSubmit: closeModal
        });
    }
});
```